# ServiceStack pagination IHasRequestFilter explanation

Tags: pagination, servicestack, query-string

I am trying to implement ServiceStack pagination and I would like to follow a pagination tutorial.

Just a quick question - What exactly is a filter in this context? I assume the filter is the part after the question mark "?"? And the attribute is the parameter? Such as `Name` in `www.myapplication/model?Name=xyz`

Thanks.

Comment: Don't link to an external thread, copy the relevant parts into your question and be clear on what exactly your question is. Also you may be interested in how [AutoQuery supports paging built-in](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#paging-and-ordering).

Comment: Hi mythz, thanks for the link. I will look into it later. I have removed the links. So is Filter ServiceStack's term for querystring or?

Comment: But you've not included the relevant parts? "filter" is just a generic term that's used to filter/limit something, it's meaning is dependent on context. If the Filter refers to `?Name=xyz` it means filtering the results to only what matches the `Name=xyz` query.